# lock and unlock according to a condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In this website : [website](http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/)

code involved :

```css
/* CSS Document */

/* Float Elements
---------------------------------*/

.fl-lt {
  float: left;
}
.fl-rt {
  float: right;
}
/* Clear Floated Elements
---------------------------------*/

.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.figure {
  margin: 0px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:active {
  outline: 0px !important
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
/* Primary Styles
---------------------------------*/

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #888888;
  margin: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #222222;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #888888;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 60px 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Header Styles
---------------------------------*/

.header {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../img/pw_maze_black_2X.png) left top repeat;
  padding: 280px 0;
}
.logo {
  width: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto 35px;
}
.header h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 0 0 22px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.we-create {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 35px 0 55px;
}
.wp-pic {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.we-create li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #bcbcbc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
.we-create li:first-child {
  background: none;
}
.start-button {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.start-button li a {
  color: #fff;
}
.link {
  padding: 15px 35px;
  background: #7cc576;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7cc576 !important;
  background: #fff;
}
.link:active,
.link:focus {
  background: #7cc576;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff !important;
}
/* Navigation
---------------------------------*/

.main-nav-outer {
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -3px #ececec;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.main-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.main-nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 1px;
}
.main-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #222222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 17px 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.main-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7cc576;
}
.small-logo {
  padding: 0 32px;
}
.main-section {
  padding: 90px 0 110px;
}
/* Portfolio
---------------------------------*/

.Portfolio-nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 45px 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.Portfolio-nav li {
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline;
}
.Portfolio-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #222222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.Portfolio-nav li a:hover {
  background: #7cc576;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.portfolioContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.Portfolio-box {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}
.Portfolio-box img {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.Portfolio-box img:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.Portfolio-nav li a.current {
  background: #7cc576;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/* no transition on .isotope container */

.isotope .isotope-item {
  /* change duration value to whatever you like */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.main-section.paddind {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Clients
---------------------------------*/

.client-part {
  background: url(../img/section-bg1.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 55px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.client-part-haead {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 41px;
  margin: 30px 0 10px;
  font-family: ''Open Sans',sans-serif';
  font-style: italic;
}
.client {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.client li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.client li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.client li a img {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.client li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.client li a h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.client li a span {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.quote-right {
  font-style: normal;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #7cc576;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  line-height: 68px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #7cc576;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.quote-right:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.c-logo-part {
  background: #7cc576;
  padding: 25px 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
.c-logo-part ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.c-logo-part ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 25px;
}
.c-logo-part ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.main-section.team {
  padding: 85px 0;
}
.main-section.team h6 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.portfolioContainer {
  max-width: 1140px;
}
/* Animation Timers
---------------------------------*/

.delay-02s {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.delay-03s {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.delay-04s {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.delay-05s {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.delay-06s {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.delay-07s {
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
.delay-08s {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.delay-09s {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
.delay-1s {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
.delay-12s {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
span.fa-stack.fa-5x.has-badge {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
}
#unlocked li:before {
  content: '\2713';
  display: inline-block;
  color: green;
  margin-left: -65px;
  padding: 0 9px 0 0;
}
#unlocked li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#locked li:before {
  content: '\274c';
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  margin-left: -65px;
  padding: 0 9px 0 0;
}
#locked li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">

  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="img/x-icon">

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,800italic,700italic,600italic,400italic,300italic,800,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">.pie {behavior:url(PIE.htc);}</style><![endif]-->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-scrolltofixed.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/classie.js"></script>
  <script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylebadge.css">


</head>

<body>
  <header class="header" id="header">
    <!--header-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <figure class="logo animated fadeInDown delay-07s">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
        </a>
      </figure>
      <h1 class="animated fadeInDown delay-07s">Welcome To Knight Studios</h1>
      <ul class="we-create animated fadeInUp delay-1s">
        <li>We are a digital agency that loves crafting beautiful websites.</li>
      </ul>
      <a class="link animated fadeInUp delay-1s" href="#">Get Started</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!--header-end-->

  <nav class="main-nav-outer" id="test">
    <!--main-nav-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#header">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#service">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Portfolio">Badges</a>
        </li>
        <li class="small-logo">
          <a href="#header">
            <img src="img/small-logo.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#client">Clients</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#team">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="res-nav_click" href="#"><i class="fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--main-nav-end-->


  <section class="main-section paddind" id="Portfolio">
    <!--main-section-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Badges</h2>
      <h6></h6>
      <div class="portfolioFilter">
        <ul class="Portfolio-nav wow fadeIn delay-02s">
          <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">All Badges</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter=".branding">Salesforce</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter=".photography">L & TD</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="portfolioContainer wow fadeInUp delay-04s">
      <div class=" Portfolio-box branding">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count=10>
         <div class="badgesize">
                 <a href="#"><img src="img/66.png" alt=""></a>
         </div>
             </span>
        <h3>Completionist</h3>
        <p>Didnot submit timesheet for a week</p>

        <ul id="unlocked">
          <li>UNLOCKED</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="locked">
          <li>LOCKED</li>
        </ul>
      </div>



      <div class="Portfolio-box branding">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count=15>
          <div class="badgesize">
                  <a href="#"><img src="img/11.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
              </span>
        <h3>Get A LIFE</h3>
        <p>Logged greater than 60 hours for the week</p>
        <ul id="unlocked">
          <li>UNLOCKED</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="locked">
          <li>LOCKED</li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div class=" Portfolio-box branding">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count=2>
          <div class="badgesize">
                  <a href="#"><img src="img/22.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
              </span>
        <h3>Slogger</h3>
        <p>Logged greater than 55 hours for the week</p>
        <ul id="unlocked">
          <li>UNLOCKED</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="locked">
          <li>LOCKED</li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div class=" Portfolio-box branding">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count=100>
          <div class="badgesize">
                  <a href="#"><img src="img/1.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
              </span>
        <h3>Into The Game</h3>
        <p>Starts Playing the Game</p>
        <ul id="unlocked">
          <li>UNLOCKED</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="locked">
          <li>LOCKED</li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div class=" Portfolio-box branding">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count=100>
          <div class="badgesize">
                  <a href="#"><img src="img/2.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
              </span>
        <h3>Hipster</h3>
        <p>Branding</p>
        <ul id="unlocked">
          <li>UNLOCKED</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="locked">
          <li>LOCKED</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class=" Portfolio-box branding">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count=20>
          <div class="badgesize">
                  <img src="img/7.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
              </span>
        <h3>Windmills</h3>
        <p>Photography</p>
        <ul id="unlocked">
          <li>UNLOCKED</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="locked">
          <li>LOCKED</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class=" Portfolio-box photography">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count=0>
          <div class="badgesize">
          <img src="img/ltd1.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
         </span>
        <h3>Windmills</h3>
        <p>Photography</p>
        <ul id="unlocked">
          <li>UNLOCKED</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="locked">
          <li>LOCKED</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class=" Portfolio-box photography">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count=200>
          <div class="badgesize">
                  <img src="img/ltd2.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
              </span>
        <h3>Windmills</h3>
        <p>Photography</p>
        <ul id="unlocked">
          <li>UNLOCKED</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="locked">
          <li>LOCKED</li>
        </ul>
      </div>



    </div>
  </section>
  <!--main-section-end-->

  <section class="business-talking">
    <!--business-talking-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Let’s Talk Business.</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--business-talking-end-->


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
      $('#test').scrollToFixed();
      $('.res-nav_click').click(function() {
        $('.main-nav').slideToggle();
        return false

      });

    });
  </script>

  <script>
    wow = new WOW({
      animateClass: 'animated',
      offset: 100
    });
    wow.init();
  </script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {

      $('.main-nav li a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 102
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        /*
   if you don't want to use the easing effects:
   $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
   }, 1000);
   */
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    })
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {


      var $container = $('.portfolioContainer'),
        $body = $('body'),
        colW = 375,
        columns = null;


      $container.isotope({
        // disable window resizing
        resizable: true,
        masonry: {
          columnWidth: colW
        }
      });

      $(window).smartresize(function() {
        // check if columns has changed
        var currentColumns = Math.floor(($body.width() - 30) / colW);
        if (currentColumns !== columns) {
          // set new column count
          columns = currentColumns;
          // apply width to container manually, then trigger relayout
          $container.width(columns * colW)
            .isotope('reLayout');
        }

      }).smartresize(); // trigger resize to set container width
      $('.portfolioFilter a').click(function() {
        $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({

          filter: selector,
        });
        return false;
      });

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have  two conditions for badges :(below are the two badges)

[image: unlocked badge]
[image: locked badge]

Issue :

when the count (which appears on the upper right side of the badge as "10" and "0" here) is greater than "0" then "unlocked with check mark" should be displayed else "locked with cross" should be dispalyed and it should be faded as in hover effect we see normally.

Its quite tricky for me.Kindly help,if anyone can.Thanks a lot.God bless.

Comment: Your code in the snippet already displays errors...

Comment: what is the relation to php here? since you tagged as such. No relevance/code, then it needs to be removed. Please don't spam tag.

Comment: code is error free.the website is running fine if you go to the link at the top.I couldnot give the entire code,as no space.I gave all the html css and js related to the badge i am talking about here.Anyways,Thanks.God bless

Comment: m using php here in the back-end .May be a way to solve it with php that I am not able to find.And,maybe some web developer might have come across something similar.Thanks a lot. @Fred-ii-

Comment: without  (php) source code to go on, would make this unclear/too broad Jane.

Comment: also m retrieving the number count from sql server .May be a way to echo with some condition @Fred-ii-

Comment: M just searching for some solution or hint. Sry fr offending. @Fred-ii-

Comment: You are showing way too much code. No one is going to wade through all that and try to decipher what you need to do. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @PatrickEvans.I will keep that in mind.Its a challenging question.So I thought someone may way to run the code or add something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate all `Portfolio-box`, check when they have a span badge with data-count > 0, then show/hide the locked/unlocked

```
$.each($('.Portfolio-box'), function() {
    var count = $(this).children('has-badge').attr('data-count');
    if(count > 0) {
        $(this).children('ul.locked').hide();
        $(this).children('ul.unlocked').show();
    } else {
        $(this).children('ul.locked').show();
        $(this).children('ul.unlocked').hide();
    }
});
```

And in your html replace

```
<ul id="unlocked">
<ul id="locked">
```

For

```
<ul class="unlocked">
<ul class="locked">
```

Another option you could do is to use PHP to not generate the HTML for locked/unlocked based on your business rule, something like:

```
<?php if($badgeCount >0): ?>
<ul class="unlocked">
....
</ul>
<? else: ?>
<ul class="locked">
....
</ul>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sounds great.Thanks a ton.I will go through it and get back.God Bless

Comment: @ Felippe I tried what you said.ur code looks perfect ,but no luck so far.Plz see this https://jsfiddle.net/dkjz1z4k/ .I have the js in the html.Kindly help.thanks a lot.

Comment: Plz ignore the images.The lock and unlock is visible in the fiddle.Thanks a lot. @Felippe